# How do you define a space of a cone in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let A be a $m \times r$ matrix, the cone generated by its columns is:

$$ C_{A} = \{ Ax \mid x \geq 0\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$$

My question is, why is the word cone used to define this? I tried an example in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to get an intuition of this and it made sense to me, because if we only have two independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ then we basically cover a triangle (which I guess is the equivalent of a cone in 2D?).

Anyway, in 3D it made less sense to me because I expected a circular cone to be covered, but it seemed more like a 3D pyramid. Is that correct? Or maybe what I need is a rigorous definition of a cone and see if $C_{A}$ satisfies that definition. Does someone have an idea of why the word cone was used and how to justify it? Either rigorously or intuitively?

---

Edit:

after some googling it seems thats the definition of [cone in linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_(linear_algebra)) is:

> In linear algebra, a (linear) cone is a subset of a vector space that is closed under multiplication by positive scalars

Kind of a unsatisfying definition  because it didn't really look like a cone in $\mathbb{R}^3$, more like a triangular based pyramid (if we have the rank of A to be 3). Am I wrong? Or why is that called a cone?

Comment: The word used is cone simply because it looks like a cone. It is hard to imagine what else you are after...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez just a confirmation that, what you said is it. It really isn't a cone right? That what I want to confirm.

Comment: Well, that depends on what is a cone for you (and you have not told us...)

Comment: "One of the miseries of life is that everybody names things a little bit wrong, and so it makes everything a little harder to understand." -- Richard Feynman ([See 4:56 in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKWGGDXe5MA))

Comment: Depending on the context, the thing you describe could be called a polyhedral cone, to distinguish it from more general cones.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I did say in my question that it wasn't a circular cone... thought I didn't explicitly say what a cone was. I just wanted something with not a slanted height and a circular base, the base being pretty important in the definition of cone (like an classical ice cream cone).

Comment: @littleO yea tell me about, just waste 2 hours of lecture time because of the freaking word cone (that confused me terribly)... thnx anyway.

Comment: If you are in a lecture, you should ask your lecturer as soon as you are confused. Trust me: there are very few things more disheartening for a teacher than spending two hours talking to someone who is completely lost!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I usually don't reserve question but since he didn't make a big fuss about using the word cone, I was embarrassed to ask...next time I won't make the same mistake. Thanks for your support/advice :)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez There's a word missing in your last comment, isn't there?